# Data usage monitoring

Tags: linux, data-visualization, network-monitor

I want to get one of those wireless hubs that I can carry in the car to have  internet access (with a data plan) on my devices (phone, tablet and laptop) when there's no Wifi available.

I'm not sure which plan I need - or how many GBs.

Is there any software that monitors how many bandwidth (if that's the correct term) used by applications, so I can have a rough estimate of the size of plan I will need? I won't be watching hours and hours of HD Netflix content on the road, and I won't play online games and that sort of things, but I always have the same 4-5 websites/tools open, and I would like to see how much data they use.

I know a few Linux command lines that can show me how much is going in/out at a certain moment in time, but I would like a software that can generate a history or reports, daily/weekly/monthly, to see exactly what's "eating" most of the bandwidth.

Does such a tool exist? I'm on Linux, ElementaryOS distro (Ubuntu based).